# Blender keeps freezing

Tags: animation, performance

I am new on blender, and I seems to have one really annoying problem. I thought my PC is pretty good but seems as I am not right.

i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20 GHz
32GB RAM
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

and my PC seems to barely handle? I mean in most case with Subdivision surface makes my PC go wild and most of times just close down blender. If I do some animation and try to see how does it look like, its nearly to impossible to play it. My blender goes "Not Resposing" a lot of times, even when moving items, but happens usually when I am further down with the project.
Wonder if I there is anyway to boost it up? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading one version? Although the problem might be something else, but you can always try using different versions.

Comment: What levels is the subdivision surface on your object? How many faces does the object have?

Comment: above if I go 10 if usually goes crazy - hard to say how many faces

Comment: Really! @user124943 10 Subdivisions is millions of faces! Don't go above 3 or 4 or 6 at the maximum! No wonder your computer crashes. It is supposed to crash under such high loads. Even 4 subdivisions are very high!

Answer (score 0):

10 Subdivisions are too high. Thats an extreme amount of subdivisions. 4 subdivisions are also very high, and sometimes 5 or 6 subdivisions makes your pc crash while rendering. Subdivisions should be around 2 or 3 subdivisios unless you want to increase  your subdivisions and go upto millions of faces. If only one object has millions of subdivisions/faces, then of course your whole pc should crash when trying to move that onject, not only blender. Why do you need 10 subdivisions anyway? Thats a very very very extreme amount.